# How do I add every file's size?

Tags: java

I am printing out filesize of every file in X directory but I would like to know how do I add them?
Here's my code

```
import java.io.File;
public class abcc {
public static void main( String [] args ) {
    File nam = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32");
  if(nam.exists() && !nam.isDirectory())
      System.out.println(nam.getName() + " exists and is   " + nam.length()/1024 + " kb");

  else if (nam.isDirectory())
      System.out.println("");
  else
      System.out.println("0 ");



if (nam.isDirectory()){
for( File f : nam.listFiles()){
    System.out.println( f.length() );
}


}else if(nam.isFile()){


}}}
```

Output is something like this
1
2
3
how do I get a single output that is sum of these numbers?
Thank you

Comment: By defining a variable, and using `+`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the sum in a variable. So declare a variable for it, e.g.

```
int totalSize = 0;
```

Inside the loop, you need to add `totalSize` with each file length:

```
totalSize += f.length();
```

Then finally print the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable for the total size, and then keep on adding the sizes of indiavidual files. Since **f.length()** returns **long**, you need a varaiable of data type **long**.
I have edited your code, and now it looks like :

```
import java.io.File;
public class abcc 
{
    public static void main( String [] args ) 
    {
        long total = 0;
        File nam = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32");
        if(nam.exists() && !nam.isDirectory())
              System.out.println(nam.getName() + " exists and is   " + nam.length()/1024 + " kb");

        else if (nam.isDirectory())
              System.out.println("");
        else
              System.out.println("0 ");

        if (nam.isDirectory()){
              for( File f : nam.listFiles()){
                    System.out.println( f.length() );
                    total = total+f.length();
              }

        }else if(nam.isFile()){

        }
        System.out.println("Total Size : "+total);
      }
}
```

This code displays the total size of the files at the end.

Comment: @user3550204 I request you to please accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a recursive subroutine. Here is my suggested code:

```
import  java.io.File;

public class DirectoryScan {


    public static void main(String[] args){

        File toScan = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32");

        System.out.println("Total size is: " + getSize(toScan)/1024 + " kb");

    }

    public static long getSize(File name){
        if(name.isDirectory()){//if it is a directory, call this method on all the files in the directory.
              long size = 0;
              for( File f : name.listFiles()){
                   size += getSize(f);//get the size for the directory and add the size of that directory to the total size
              }
              return size;//return the size of this directory
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(name.getName() + " exists and is   " + name.length()/1024 + " kb");
            return name.length();//return the filesize.
        }
    }
}
```

Basically getSize(File) is called recursively (for each folder/file) and returns the size of that folder/file.